# Minecraft won’t open because it says it’s already running

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So I’ve seen this question asked on this site before. However, I still can’t come to a fix that works. I haven’t gotten on Minecraft in a while and thought I’d give it a shot again, so I open it, hit the play button.. it just loads and never actually gets anywhere. I hit play for a second time, now it says that it is “already running” however this is clearly not true.

I have deleted and redownloaded the game, I have checked my background tasks to make sure that Java is not still currently running (it’s not.) I’ve gone under the %appdata%, deleted the “.minecraft” folder, deleted minecraft and redownloaded it *again* still nothing works. I’ve even deleted and redownloaded Java, still nothing.

I’m at a loss here and have tried just about everything I know to do so thought I’d turn to here and see if anyone else has any ideas? I thought possibly it was just a bug that was needing to be fixed, but if that’s the case, it’s been a while now and still not working.

Anyways, thanks to anyone who offers some advice cus I don’t know what to do and it’s becoming aggravating.

Comment: What happens if you run `taskkill /im javaw.exe /f /t` in command prompt (assuming you're on windows)?

Comment: @Penguin Yes, sorry, I am using windows, probably should have mentioned. I just now tried that and it says that “javaw.exe” is not found.

Comment: okay sorry don't know how to help you further then (what that did is check if Minecraft really was running and if so kill it, I know you said you didn't see it in task manager but sometimes we miss things)

Comment: @Penguin Alright, well thanks for the help anyways. I’ve checked a good couple times in task manager, pretty sure it’s not there.

Comment: yes it is 100% not running since that command failed, hope you find the issue!